# Compare two hashed password using same salt using SHA-256 algorith in Java, Spring security?

Tags: java, spring-security, sha256

I need some guidance on the scenario where I need to check the password coming from UI form (i.e, `Authentication` object) which I need to hashed using `SHA-256 + constant salt`(before making comparison) and password coming from DB (DB also has hashed password + salt)  using Spring Security.

I am looking to compare these two **different** hashed value generated using same **SALT** value. How we can do it in java? Could anyone please share me a sample code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You compare the passwords using string equality. `dbPassword.equals(inputPassword)`, where both are salted and hashed.

Comment: I'm looking to compare two different hashed value generated from same salt using SHA-256 algorith. Please guide with code.  Thanks, Neha

Comment: Provide an example because the question seems confusing. If the inputs to SHA-256 are different the outputs will be different. SHA-256 does not have a "salt", an HMAC does, please explain the salt. Please provide some code.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply compare the two password strings `passwordA.equals(passwordB)` ...

**This has some security shortcomings:**

1. Passwords should not be handled as strings, but as char or byte arrays: [see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java)
2. An Equal comparison is (theoretically) vulnerable to a timing-attack: [see a discussion about a solution in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191112/how-do-i-implement-a-string-comparison-in-java-that-takes-the-same-amount-of-tim)
3. It might be wise to use standard-tool to do security related things (even when they seem to be simple). Spring security has a ton of tools that can do that for you. Have a look at [BCryptPasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) for example. Using well tested and maintained frameworks for security purposes is always a good idea.

   ```
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    ...
    boolean result = passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, hashedPassword);
   ```

---

**Also**: Use a proper Algorithm for Password-Hashing! [See this Answer on SO for some proposals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1844539/2881450)

SHA-256 is not one of them. Spring Security gives you the right tools for the jobs, so you could just use them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me you're looking to compare two separate hashed values created using same salt. Am I right ? If yes, so here is the sample program taking a reference from https://ashishpshukla.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/sample-java-code-for-password-encryption-using-secure-hash-algorithm-sha-256/

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class PasswordEncoder {
    private static PasswordEncoder instance;
    private final static int ITERATION_COUNT = 5;

    private PasswordEncoder() {  }

    public static synchronized PasswordEncoder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            PasswordEncoder returnPasswordEncoder = new PasswordEncoder();
            return returnPasswordEncoder;
        }
        else
            return instance;
    }

    public synchronized String encode(String password, String saltKey)throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        String encodedPassword = null;
        byte[] salt = base64ToByte(saltKey);

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.reset();
        digest.update(salt);

        byte[] btPass = digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION_COUNT; i++) {
            digest.reset();
            btPass = digest.digest(btPass);
        }

        encodedPassword = byteToBase64(btPass);
        return encodedPassword;
    }

    private byte[] base64ToByte(String str) throws IOException {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] returnbyteArray = decoder.decodeBuffer(str);
        return returnbyteArray;
    }

    private String byteToBase64(byte[] bt) {
        BASE64Encoder endecoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        String returnString = endecoder.encode(bt);
        return returnString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        String password = "Secrete@343";
        String saltKey = "PveFT7isDjGYFTaYhc2Fzw==";
        String hash1,hash2 = null;

        // Assume from UI
        PasswordEncoder encoder1 = PasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        hash1 = encoder1.encode(password, saltKey);
        System.out.println(hash1);

        // Assume the same present in db
        PasswordEncoder encoder2 = PasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        hash2 = encoder2.encode(password, saltKey);
        System.out.println(hash2);

        if(hash1.equalsIgnoreCase(hash2))
            System.out.println("Both hash Matches..");
        else
            System.out.println("Hash matches fails..");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
8WgbLik5EbdtJY4OWm2ZQ0tHiU2lmvXNVrPhFDz3W2Y=
8WgbLik5EbdtJY4OWm2ZQ0tHiU2lmvXNVrPhFDz3W2Y=
Both hash Matches..
```

Comment: Please add a description of how the salt is being used with the password.