# Encryption/decryption: HMAC tags don't match in decryption method

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to code encryption and decryption methods that will encrypt/decrypt a message.

In the encrypt method, it will take in a string. It will read in a public key and be used in a RSA cipher. Then, the message will be encrypted with an AES Cipher that has a AES Key and IV. Then, a HMAC tag will be generated with the ciphertext encrypted AES by using a HMAC key. The AES Key and HMAC key are concatenated together and encrypted by RSA Cipher. The method will return a JSONObject that contains: RSA ciphertext, AES ciphertext, the AES IV, and HMAC tag. They are byte arrays that are converted into hex strings.

In the decrypt method, it will take in the JSON Object, which will be parsed. It will read in a private key that will be used in a RSA cipher. The RSA cipher will be used to decrypt the concatenated keys. Once decrypted the keys will be separated to AES Key and HMAC key. Then, new HMAC tag will be generated on the AES Ciphertext. Compare the tag from the encryption and the new tag. If they are equal, then decrypt the AES ciphertext and get the message.

When I run my code, there are no errors, but it does not decrypt because the 2 tags don't match. I don't know why.

The public and private keys are `.der` files that were converted from `.pem` files.

Please help me. Thanks!

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import org.json.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class CryptographicTools 
{
    /**
     * This method encrypts a message
     * @param message String message to be encrypted
     * @return a JSONObject 
     */
    public JSONObject encryptMessage(String message)
    {
        JSONObject output = new JSONObject(); // instantiate JSONObject

        try
        {
            //read in public key
            byte[] publicKeyBytes = readKeyFromFile("public.der");//pem convert to der

            //turn bytes into public key
            X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes); //encodes the bytes
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); //make the key a RSA instance

            //initialize RSA object and public key
            Cipher RSAObject = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding"); //with OAEP   
            RSAObject.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec)); //create RSA encryption cipher with a generated public key

            //generate 256-bit AES key
            KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");//generate AES Key
            keyGen.init(256); //generate a key with 256 bits
            SecretKey AESKey = keyGen.generateKey(); //generate AES key with 256 bits

            //Create AES IV
            SecureRandom randomByteGenerator = new SecureRandom();//secure generator to generate random byes for  IV
            byte[] AESKeyIVArray = new byte[16];
            randomByteGenerator.nextBytes(AESKeyIVArray);//get random bytes for iv
            IvParameterSpec AES_IV = new IvParameterSpec(AESKeyIVArray); //iv object for AES object

            //initialize AES object
            Cipher AESObject = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            AESObject.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, AESKey, AES_IV); //tell the AES object to encrypt

            //encrypt message with AES
            byte[] AESciphertext = AESObject.doFinal(message.getBytes());

            //generate 256-bit HMAC key
            byte[] SHA256KeyArray = new byte[32];//256 bits
            randomByteGenerator.nextBytes(SHA256KeyArray);//generate random bits for key
            SecretKeySpec HMACKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec (SHA256KeyArray,"HmacSHA256"); //make the key
            Mac HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256"); //initialize HMAC
            HMAC.init(HMACKeySpec);//put key in cipher
            byte [] HMACTag = HMAC.doFinal(AESciphertext);//generate HMAC tag

            //concatenate AES and HMAC keys
            byte[] AESKeyByte = AESKey.getEncoded();///turn AESKey to byte array
            byte[] HMACKeySpecByte = HMACKeySpec.getEncoded();///turn HMAXKey to byte array
            byte[] concatenatedKeys = new byte[AESKeyByte.length + HMACKeySpecByte.length];//new array for concatenated keys

            //combine keys in new array
            System.arraycopy(AESKeyByte, 0, concatenatedKeys, 0, AESKeyByte.length);
            System.arraycopy(HMACKeySpecByte, 0, concatenatedKeys, AESKeyByte.length, HMACKeySpecByte.length);

            //encrypt keys with RSA object
            byte[] RSAciphertext = RSAObject.doFinal(concatenatedKeys);

            //put RSA ciphertext, AES ciphertext, AES_IV and HMAC tag in JSon
            //save byte[] as Strings in hex
            output.put("RSAciphertext", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(RSAciphertext));
            output.put("AESciphertext", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(AESciphertext));
            output.put("AES_IV", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(AES_IV.getIV()));
            output.put("HMACTag", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(HMACTag));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString() +e.getMessage()); //error message
        }

        return output; //return as JSON Object
    }

    /**
     * This method decrypts a message
     * @param jsonObjectEncrypted
     * @return message as string
     */
    public String decrypt (JSONObject jsonObjectEncrypted)
    {
        String message="";
        try
        {
            //recover RSA ciphertext from JSON
            String RSACiphertextString=jsonObjectEncrypted.getString("RSAciphertext");
            byte[] recoveredRSAciphertext = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(RSACiphertextString); //convert hex string to byte array

            //recover AES ciphertext from JSON
            String AESCiphertextString=jsonObjectEncrypted.getString("AESciphertext");
            byte[] recoveredAESciphertext = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(AESCiphertextString); //convert hex string to byte array

            //recover AES IV from JSON
            String AES_IVString=jsonObjectEncrypted.get("AES_IV").toString();
            byte[] recoveredAES_IV = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(AES_IVString); //convert hex string to byte array
            //recover HMACTag from JSON
            String HMACTagString=jsonObjectEncrypted.getString("HMACTag");
            byte[] recoveredHMACTag = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(HMACTagString); //convert hex string to byte array

            //read in private key
            byte[] privateKeyBytes = readKeyFromFile("private.der");//pem convert to der

            //turn bytes into private key
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

            //initialize RSA object and private key
            Cipher RSAObject = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding"); //with OAEP   
            RSAObject.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateSpec)); //create RSA encryption cipher with a generated private key

            //Decrypt concatenated keys with RSA object
            byte[] concatenatedKeys = RSAObject.doFinal(recoveredRSAciphertext);

            //split the concatenated keys
            byte[] AESKey = new byte[concatenatedKeys.length/2];
            byte[] HMACKey = new byte[concatenatedKeys.length/2];
            System.arraycopy(concatenatedKeys, 0,AESKey,0,AESKey.length); //Copy half into AESKey
            System.arraycopy(concatenatedKeys, AESKey.length,HMACKey,0,HMACKey.length); //Copy Other half into HMACKey

            //generate HMACTag
            SecretKeySpec HMACKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec (HMACKey,"HmacSHA256"); //make the key
            Mac HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            HMAC.init(HMACKeySpec);//initialize with HMAC Key
            byte [] newHMACTag = HMAC.doFinal(recoveredAESciphertext); //generate HMACTag with AES Ciphertext

            if(recoveredHMACTag.equals(newHMACTag)) //encrypt message if tags are equal
            {
                //initialize AES object
                Cipher AESObject = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                AESObject.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec (AESKey,"AES"), new IvParameterSpec(recoveredAES_IV)); //tell the AES object to encrypt
                message = new String (AESObject.doFinal(recoveredAESciphertext), "US-ASCII");//encrypt AES ciphertext and save as string

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Message cannot be decrypted.");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: "+e.toString()+": "+e.getMessage()); //error message
        }

        return message; //return plaintext
    }

    /**
     * This method reads bytes of a key from a file  into a byte array
     * @param fileName type of key
     * @return byte array
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public byte[] readKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java array doesn't implement `.equals()` the way you'd want it to ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777279/49489)). Try replacing this check:

```
recoveredHMACTag.equals(newHMACTag)
```

by this one:

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(recoveredHMACTag, newHMACTag)
```

I can't say that's *all* that could be causing it to go wrong, but it's the first thing I would check.

Comment: It is best to use a constant time comparison function such as this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30981412/1816580

Comment: A constant time comparison is rarely necessary when comparing hash values and this does not seem to be such a case. I would be interested to see the concepts of such an attack here.

Comment: @zaph If an attacker knows (or can guess) the contents of the message they can do a bit-flipping attack to change it (garbling a block in the process with CBC). Then they do a timing attack using this new message to get a valid HMAC. The end result is they’ve got a forged message that is accepted as valid. Tricky to pull off and might not be applicable in all situations, but that’s the attack. (In this case it’s worse—the IV isn’t covered by the MAC so an attacker can change the contents of the first block pretty much at will).

Comment: I don't understand how the timing attack applies to this hash, getting one bit right does not seem to help to get the other bits right since a one bit change in the input changes approximately 50% of the hash output bits. I did not say there were no cases where a timing attack on a hash will not work, just not this one. As noted not including the IV in the HMAC is an error.

Comment: @zaph in this scenario the input to the hash doesn’t change. The attacker has a modified message, and in order to get it accepted needs to have a valid authentication tag for it. They repeatedly modify the _tag_, trying to get it to match the calculated value, (which is constant since the message and key don’t change).

Comment: OK, but no where in that comment is there a reference to how a non-constant-time hash comparison (as compared to a constant-time comparison) is involved and that is the crux of the discussion.