# Java : A method which accepts a string as a parameter, what input validation would make the method defensible?

Tags: java, string, validation, defensive-programming

**Homework Problem**:: I came across this question in a **quiz of secure coding**:

When creating a defensible method in java that accepts a string and compares it to a predefined value, what input validation would make the method defensible?

```
public static final String SLIDES="Slides";

public static final boolean isAcceptableType(String type){
if(________________________________){
return false;
}
if(!type.equals(SLIDES){
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

**My goal is to fill the if condition** that will make the method defensible.
**I can't change the other code**.

According to my understanding we have to **validate the method parameter** **to check if its a valid string**. so that it will not throw any exception when it will be compared with SLIDES

I tried if(type==null) but I got incorrect result.

Please help me with this question. :)

Comment: "defensible" against what? Are you just asking how to check if `type` is equal to `SLIDES`? `return Objects.equals(type, SLIDES);` is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: Think about what could break that method. It basically returns true if `type.equals(SLIDES)` - under which circumstances could that call break/cause an exception?

Comment: You tried `if (type==null)` and got the incorrect result? What result did you get? What result were you trying to get?

Comment: Your null check answer looks good to me. If there are any humans (a forum maybe?) involved in that quiz, try to reach out to them why it was rejected.

Comment: "defensible" is not a common term. If this is a homework problem, then share any definition you have been given for it.

Comment: Is this about side-channel attacks and making sure the time taken does not depend on the input string? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191112/how-do-i-implement-a-string-comparison-in-java-that-takes-the-same-amount-of-tim

Comment: According to my understanding we have to validate the method parameter to check if its a valid string. so that it will not throw any exception when it will be compared with SLIDES

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear why

```
if (type == null)
```

wouldn't work.

If your goal is to ensure that `type` is equal to `SLIDES`, then you can either use:

```
if (!Objects.equals(type, SLIDES))
```

or

```
if (!SLIDES.equals(type))
```

Both will handle the case of `type == null`.

Comment: That is functionally equivalent to adding a null check in that first blank, though, and that answer got rejected. I suppose other than filling in the blank nothing else is allowed. The question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Use spaces. The answer is: `type == null`. As in:

```
if(type == null){
   return false;
```